# I'm getting the error TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, compiler-errors

```
richness = int(input("How many species are in your ecosystem? "))
population = 0
for x in range (1, (richness+1)):
    population = population + int(input("What's the population of species " + str(x) + "? "))
print("Your species richness is " + str(richness))
print("Your simpsons biodiversity index is " + str(1-((population(population-1))/(richness(richness-1)))))
```

I wrote this for a Bio project, and I can't figure out what the problem is. It seems to be coming from the last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `population(population - 1)` (on your last line) which is treating `population` as a function, when it's a variable.

If you meant' to multiple them, you have to explicitly state that with `population * (population - 1)`. The same problem is present for `richness`

Answer (score 1):

thats right it is

```
print("Your simpsons biodiversity index is " + str(1-((population * (population-1))/(richness * (richness-1)))))
```

you must signify multiplication